# test mongo db connection php script

Tags: mongodb

I am quite new to Mongo, been playing around with it but can't find way to test connection to db like for instance how i would test it with my mysql, here is script i normally use for mysql: https://gist.github.com/chales/11359952.

How can i test connection to mongo db with php script? I have tried to accomplish this with php script but not sure what functions to call:

```
    $m = new MongoClient('ip address of server');
    $db = $m->selectDB('dbname');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'collectionname');
```

Comment: I would start with the MongoDB [PHP driver tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php). It's not clear what you want to test, but so far all you have is set up. A next step might be `$cursor = $collection->find()` if you want to find all documents in that collection.

Comment: Thank you Stennie, I also saw that document. All I want to test is if connection successful from front end to the backend of the database. The example in the link (https://gist.github.com/chales/11359952) to the MySQL test is exactly  what I want to do, but only for Mongo DB.

Comment: The equivalent to the referenced gist would be connecting and listing collection names: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getcollectionnames.php. The `MongoClient()` constructor should connect before returning, so if you aren't getting any exceptions the connection probably worked. Fetching results of a query or command might be helpful to confirm you've connected to the expected database or collection. You could also try changing to an invalid server address to make sure exceptions are being returned as you expect.

Comment: That looks like better way to test. Added 2 collections but not getting any output.